# Insert data to the sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, onclicklistener

i am trying to send data to database but i,m getting this error

under this line `(db.insertData(fname, lname, pnumber, email, nic))` the error is
`insertdata() in databasehelper cannot be applied to fname:java.lang.String fname(android.widget.EditText)`

the code is looks like this
` public void onClick(View view) {

```
            if (fname.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 ||
                    lname.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 ||
                    pnumber.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 ||
                    email.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 ||
                    nic.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(AddEmployee.this, "Complete all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (db.insertData(fname, lname, pnumber, email, nic)) {
                Toast.makeText(AddEmployee.this, "Employee Register Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fname.setText("");
                lname.setText("");
                pnumber.setText("");
                email.setText("");
                nic.setText("");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(AddEmployee.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }`
```

Database Helper is like this

```
public boolean insertData(String fname, String lname, Integer pnumber, String email, String nic) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(FNAME, fname);
            contentValues.put(LNAME, lname);
            contentValues.put(PNUMBER, pnumber);
            contentValues.put(EMAIL, email);
            contentValues.put(NIC, nic);

            long result = db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, contentValues);
            return result != -1;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you are passing edittext to DB but you have to pass string
So instead of fname write fname.getText().toString() in your else if and this will solve your problem